# how to get values from same table using SQL query or HQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, hql

hi I need to fetch data from below table where I will pass only id 5 but I need to get all 5 rows(as for orgid 5, approving org is 4 so we select it, similarly for orgid 4, approving org is 3 and it goes on till approving org id 0)

```
 ORG_ID  name   APPROVING_ORG_ID
  1     name 1     0
  2     name2      1
  3     name 3     2
  4     name 4     3
  5     name 5     4
```

Comment: Is the approving depth limited? E.g. not more than 5?

Answer (score 0):

try to create function in sql. this might be help you out

```
  CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `GetAllNode`(GivenID INT) RETURNS text CHARSET latin1
        DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        DECLARE rv,q,queue,queue_children TEXT;
        DECLARE queue_length,front_id,pos INT;
        SET rv = '';
        SET queue = GivenID;
        SET queue_length = 1;
        WHILE queue_length > 0 DO
            SET front_id = queue;
            IF queue_length = 1 THEN
                SET queue = '';
            ELSE
                SET pos = LOCATE(',',queue) + 1;
                SET q = SUBSTR(queue,pos);
                SET queue = q;
            END IF;
            SET queue_length = queue_length - 1;
            SELECT IFNULL(qc,'') INTO queue_children
            FROM (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(ORG_ID AS CHAR(50))) AS qc
            FROM `yourtablename` WHERE `APPROVING_ORG_ID` = front_id) A ;
            IF LENGTH(queue_children) = 0 THEN
                IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
                    SET queue_length = 0;
                END IF;
            ELSE
                IF LENGTH(rv) = 0 THEN
                    SET rv = queue_children;
                ELSE
                    SET rv = CONCAT(rv,',',queue_children);
                END IF;
                IF LENGTH(queue) = 0 THEN
                    SET queue = queue_children;
                ELSE
                    SET queue = CONCAT(queue,',',queue_children);
                END IF;
                SET queue_length = LENGTH(queue) - LENGTH(REPLACE(queue,',','')) + 1;
            END IF;
        END WHILE;
        RETURN rv;
    END
```